# website not displaying at all, only in chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I have just moved my site to a friend's server, he has taken care of everything and the website looks great in all browsers according to him.

But he is in Spain, where i used to be too, but now im in India, and here the website does not display at all when i use chrome, it just shows a white screen. However, if i browse the source code, it shows correctly. In IE and FF it displays just fine.

UPDATE: the error is Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

And a related question can be found here: [net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING in Chrome only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608564/neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-in-chrome-only)

What could be causing this strange behaviour?

This is the site, [http://culturadigital.cc](http://culturadigital.cc/es)

UPDATE 2: if i comment out this line `FallbackResource /es/index.php` in my .htaccess file it works again, but i need this line!

Comment: Chrome gives me the following error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING.

Comment: oh, thx, i guess i should have looked for errors myself. In any case, thats weird cuz the site was working fine before changing to the new host...?

Comment: so try moving the site to another host and check if the error is still there. there are plenty of free hosts out there.