# Incomplete Chunked Encoding Error Chrome / Specific PCs

Tags: google-chrome, magento, chunked-encoding, chunked

We develop various websites for clients and have recently experienced a strange problem with a few of our "heavier" websites.

A couple of our Magento stores, and 1 other PHP based website **only** on my PC and 1 client's PC have been failing to load on Chrome and other browsers with the console error:

net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

This error is usually shown on various JS files such as:
/js/magentothem/jquery-ui.js

On refresh you can reproduce the same error multiple times, and then occasionally the site will load fine.

If you open the JS file in a separate tab the file clearly cuts off at a random point (i.e. isn't loaded fully), but after multiple refreshes will load cleanly.

It isn't just 1 file in question - it varies between JS files - the files are uploaded correctly to the server.

We have 4 PCs in the office, and it only happens on mine, but also weirdly on one of our client's machines with the same error.

We all run the same version of Chrome (including the machines that work fine).

**After investigation...**
- If I change my network cable to one of the others previously connected to a PC receiving the page fine, I still get the error

**- If I disconnect my network cable and HotSpot to my iPhone network, the sites load fine!**

I have tried disabling all forms of caching on the server, and checking error logs, all to no avail.

Can anyone shed any light on what this issue could be related to? I am convinced this error is not server related - and could be a coincidence between mine and my client's PC, but what is the question...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having the exact same issue. PHP & Apache.

Comment: We're having this problem, but it only affects Chrome on some of the PCs here in the office. Having tested the exact same site in Canary (the development version of Chrome which I have installed side-by-side with Chrome) I can access the affected sites without a problem.  I strongly suspect that the issue is down to an extension installed in Chrome, and I am on the verge of pointing the finger at the official Analytics plugin for Chrome. I'll test.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the exact same error "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" when accessing my PERL CGI script from an android phone. CGI page is being served from Apache 2.4.6 server.

To clarify the CGI script was working perfectly in IE/Chrome/FF and on Blackberry handset.

The fix was to specify the Content-length in the HTTP header to stop chunking from happening.

Here is my example, which I hope will be useful to someone as I searched online for pointers for almost two days without any avail.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use CGI;
use CGI qw( :standard );
my $body = "Hello World";
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"; 
print "Content-Length: " . length($body) . "\n"; 
print "\n"; 

print $body . "\n";
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was being caused by an adblocker, (specifically, AdBlock on Chrome for Mac). Regardless, disabling AdBlock for the affected domain resolved the problem.

Comment: Yep, AdBlock for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your href linking to large files, and the *Predict network actions* configuration in Chrome.

Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24175704/529403

Answer (score 0):

I know i had this issue before, and i always forget a possible reason:

Realtime protection on antivirus can produce this error.

Why, i don't exactly where, but if you press F5 fast enought you may be able to see your site just before gets blocked, so it could be, maybe, some library that your antivirus is capturing, or, bad referenced.

I hope someone can help with a real solution instead of turn off realtime protection

Answer (score 0):

In my case I encountered some js plugin file was too large in size. So the browser was not able to load in one go.

How I managed to resolve the issue was to divide the whole js file in chunks and put each chunk in a separate file. Now browser can load these js chunks in one go and voila!! you get it resolved.

This may be another reason of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by increasing "max_input_vars" in php.ini. I got this error while submitting form with post data more than 1000 variables.