# response.on('end') called before all chunks are received, only on my computer

Tags: node.js

I am doing the following fairly simple request in series, for a certain amount of variables (~100) (the problem also happens for different hostnames and paths, but always when a lot of similar requests are sent to the same host)

```
var http = require('http');
var request = http.request({
    hostname: 'lookup.dbpedia.org',
    path: '/api/search/KeywordSearch?QueryString=' + [VARIABLE],
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
});
request.on('response', function (response) {
    var data = [];
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data.push(chunk);
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        var object = JSON.parse(data.join(''))
    });
});
request.end();
```

The problem is that the last chunk of the response is *sometimes* not caught by `response.on('data')`, so the JSON.parse gives an error.
**What makes it extra weird is that this only happens on my computer, and not on another** (both are Windows 7).

The problem persists for node v0.12.2 and v0.12.7, and as far I could test, this is a node issue, as something like `curl` always returns the entire response.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was my antivirus real-time shield who blocked the final chunk of a request (I use Avast). So in a way, it is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608564/neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-in-chrome-only/30973783)