# WordPress timeout error ('Articles' admin link + WPML)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

In my WordPress admin when I am inside a single article in the admin panel, and I click on the 'Articles' link on the left menu, I get my a timeout in my browser. This is very strange, because it happens ONLY when I click on that link inside an article: it doesn't happen when I click it from other sections of the panel, as when I'm in the dashboard or plugins section and I want to go to articles.

The second error I receive is when I click the 'Duplicate' button inside a post to translate that content in another language. The result is the same, 5 minutes loading and timeout error which leads to crash of the browser.

All plugins are updated, as well as the WordPress version. I have already tried to disable and activate each plugin one by one and this error comes anyway, also with all plugins disabled!!

I think it's not about WordPress version or plugins but it's like there's something which the system can't manage loading inside the article...I really can't figure out any solution.

Comment: Do you have any content from the site's error log? Have you tried switching to the Twenty Sixteen (or other Twenty Something) theme and seeing if the issue still occurs?

Comment: Some suggestions about the 'Articles' link problem. This is what my console shows: "net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING" and this is the log I can read in my hosting: "Timeout waiting for output from CGI script /web/htdocs/www.informalecco.com/home/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, referer: http://www.informalecco.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=19728&action=edit&lang=it"

Comment: Have you tried another browser besides Google Chrome (where you got the `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` error)? You may need to `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in your `wp-config.php` file to get additional information on what is going on with your `admin-ajax.php` call. I'd also recommend having it output that to a file using `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` in case the `admin-ajax` response isn't visible.

Comment: Hi Michaal and thanks for taking time to answer me! I tried on Safari and it works (why??), but it gives errors on chrome and firefox. I really can't understand why, it's very strange. I tried wp_debug but it doesn't show errors on screen...but I will try your wp_debug_log

Comment: Per this question, maybe it is your computer's antivirus? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22608564/neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-in-chrome-only

Comment: Also, other thing, when you did `WP_DEBUG` did you use `WP_DEBUG_LOG` or not? If you didn't, then there is a chance the error wasn't reported because the admin-ajax call is behind the scenes and not directly rendered.

Comment: I'm using a Mac so I shouldn't have problems about antivirus I think, at this point I could end up using Safari for editing my site, to be honest I don't really consider it a solution ...!

Comment: @michaelrmcneill could you tell me where I can find the log file? ;) I also checked that article previously and I tried an option suggested in the chrome settings, but It didn't change it

Comment: The log file is written to `wp-content/debug.log`.

Comment: I see it doesn't generate any log file...I will read more here to see if I can find out a solution! thank you by now for your support!