# Symfony 4 + Apache 2.4 + mod_rewrite not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

What am I doing wrong?

This is my config on /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hello-world.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hello-world
    DocumentRoot "/home/carlos/dev/github/hello-world/public"

<Directory "/home/carlos/dev/github/hello-world/public">
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

# uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
# or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
# <Directory /var/www/project>
#     Options FollowSymlinks
# </Directory>

# optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
# which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
# not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack
<Directory /var/www/project/public/bundles>
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine Off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to access http://hello-world/index.php/lucky/number all goes right.

But with http://hello-world/lucky/number I get a 404 Not Found.

The 404 error was due I had configure two VirtualHosts. One in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf** and other in **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hello-world.conf**. I removed that in **000-default.conf**, and now I'm receiving a "500 Internal Server Error". I change this lines:

```
<Directory "/home/carlos/dev/github/hello-world/public"> 
# AllowOverride None 
# Order Allow,Deny 
Require all granted 
# Allow from All –
```

...but still I'm getting the 500.

On /var/log/apache2/project_error.log there's this message:

```
[Thu Apr 05 19:56:25.819680 2018] [core:error] [pid 4277] [client 127.0.0.1:38800] AH00125: Request exceeded the limit of 10 subrequest nesting levels due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: what is your OS?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, finally I got:

It was a misconfiguration here:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
        FallbackResource "index.php"
    </IfModule>
```

I was following what is said here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

But then I tried to do without this FallbackResource, back to what Symfony documentation gave me, with this:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        Options -MultiViews
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
    #       FallbackResource "index.php"
    </IfModule>
```

Now it's working.

Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly caused due to a bug in Apache for versions prior to Apache 2.4.18.

There was an Apache bug with FallbackResource when being called on the home page causing Apache to hang.

The Apache bug details can be found here: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58292

[I've added a PR to update the Symfony docs](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/10433#issuecomment-426900127)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using apache 2.4, have mod_rewrite already enabled, and getting something like the below in your virtualhost error log file:

> [Thu Apr 05 15:08:55.619587 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 2382] [client 10.0.1.1:51436] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /vagrant/public/

Then update your virtual host and replace:

> Order Allow,Deny
>
> Allow from All

with

> Require all granted

Also be sure to update /var/www/project/public/bundles to your actual directory.